# How to create private playlist in soundcloud from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, soundcloud

I have a google spreadsheet in drive which contains a list of soundcloud links in column I (I2:I1000).

After I have filtered the spreadsheet to give me my desired list of results ranging between (I2 and I1000), I would like to be able to run a script that:

reads the filtered soundcloud link results in the I column; then
creates a playlist of these results in my soundcloud account;
sets the playlist to private.

I am a complete newbie and have done my best to follow tutorials but it seems my specific need is too niche for any tutorial I have managed to find. Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: This depends on whether soundcloud has an api (ie rest with oauth2) then it's doable from apps script. Spend time figuring the soundcloud api and see if it can be called from apps script urlFetchApp. For oauth2 google for the github library For apps script use. post code and whats not working there so we can start helping.

Comment: You would need to use the [SoundCloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide)  You can make HTTP Requests with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`

Comment: thanks I will start with these and see how i get on